# When to throw away a bad RPG system design?

Tags: game-design

**Let's say you're putting together a custom RPG system** of yours (core mechanics of dice and conflict resolution, support mechanics, the skills, the races, the fluff, etc.)

Let's say you're making a fairly conservative system - something DnD-ish, fantasy-ish.

Let's also say you're not all that skilled and/or experienced at this kind of a designer job ... and **you botch your RPG system**.

Now, how do you objectively determine whether your system is broken?
And, more importantly, **how do you objectively define the criteria for the system possibly being so bad it only deserves to be thrown away, as a whole** (as opposed to fixing a couple of elements and hoping for improving the functionality of the system)?

*Why am I asking this? When I get my hands on a bad system design, I do get this gut feeling of the system being broken. Gut feelings are nice and all, but they do not translate to the other person. More rigorous approach is desired.*

Comment: How do you define broken? Too complicated? Some combination of rules makes it too easy to "win"? Too many different mechanics with no unity? Just like a published system, and without any features that make it better than the published system? (In short, what makes a "good answer" to your question, so the voting system works properly?)

Comment: The last bit sounds like circular logic: you put your hands on a bad design, and you get this gut feeling of it being broken, so you know it's bad design...

Comment: @ Paul Marshall: A "good answer" would touch on all kinds of broken systems (as you listed), i suppose.

Comment: @ Adriano Varoli Piazza: a true observation, but this is more difficult than that. Design is half art, so, this makes it partially an elusive problem. But to answer the worry you raised: while perceiving a "bad design", one may experience cognitive dissonance - i.e. an impression of some parts of the system being "off", inconsistent, defying logic, contradicting, or so.

Comment: I haven't had a lot of system design experience, but this seems way too broad-scoped to have a single answer. You're basically asking, indirectly, 'what makes a game system good?'.

Comment: Arg, I had a good answer to the bolded question (which appears to be his primary one), but the question got put on hold!

Comment: @PipperChip Save it!  Fortunately, "on hold" does not mean "closed", and it's very possible for this question to get reopened with a bit of editing to narrow the scope a bit, and bring it down to something more objective and less opinion-based.

Comment: @PipperChip The site will have saved the draft, should this get reopened.

Comment: @Johnny Your last line suggests that your actual problem involves talking with a collaborator(?) or someone who has asked you to review their design. Can you clarify that part? Asking for objective criteria might be a red herring, but we might be able to help if we know what practical problem you're trying to solve by finding them. Hypothetical questions, like the way this one is written right now, are rather hard to solve!

Comment: This is way too broad and opinion-based - it depends on the gamer's values.  If you're one of the RAW-lovers that require your game to compile down to logically complete code you'll value things much differently than a hippie indie RPG person who demands that their game cause High Drama(tm).

Answer (score 8):

You're designing a game to do *something*.  That something is the kind of game play experience you want it to give.

The easy part is: does this give that experience?  No? Ok, it's broken. (or, maybe it does a different kind of experience very well, but that's not what your goal was.)

Now for the "fun" (hard, grueling) part of game design - why isn't it doing that?

1. "Because of this issue that I understand well, and oh look, I have an idea to fix it."
2. "Because of this issue that I can't see a way around and I'm going to have to decide how much time and energy I want to put into figuring out how to fix it."
3. "I have no clue and I'm going to have to decide how much time and energy I want to put into figuring out what it is, and it will turn into #1 or #2 from there."

So... it's time to scrap it when your desire to fix it is less than the amount of energy you want to put in.

My practical advice, that isn't asked here, is usually the answer is to look at different games - including boardgames, card games, videogames, weird RPGS that are structured very different than your own ("No GM?", "Wait, everyone changes characters every session?" etc.) for inspiration.  You will often find what you thought was an insurmountable problem is often solved in someone ele's game and you have to decide if that's also something you can use.